# app inspection in android studio doesn't work when using real device with lineageOS

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, lineageos

when I use a virtual device in android studio, the app inspection works just fine but when i use a physical device (Redmi 9 with lineageOS 20), the app inspection menu says: "deploy a debuggable app to a device running api level 26 or higher or select a debuggable process to inspect"

[image]

I tried to root my device, disable SELinux, invalidate cashes, reboot, disable verity but nothing worked.

Comment: I don't know how app inspection works internally, but it is obvious that uses adb commands and in combination with your LineageOS device one command fails. To understand what is going wrong you can try to sniff adb communication using Wireshark. Not sure if adb as protocol is yet in Wireshark included, last time I captured adb traffic I had to load an LUA adb dissector into Wireshark to make it recognize adb traffic.